# One xaml page for multiple pages?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Simple question that I have no idea of the answer to.

Is there a way to use just one xaml page (at least one "main" page) to emulate multiple pages. i.e the same as:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), null);
```

*but* using only one page?

Thanks so much, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Frame` control to host another page inside your main page:

```
<Frame Name="subFrame" Source="MyPage.xaml" />
```

You can then use `subFrame.Navigate` as with your example.

Comment: Wouldn't this do the same thing as above? Go to a different xaml page in the view?

Comment: I've updated the code slightly - it will only navigate the page within the frame control - the rest of your page around the frame will stay the same.

Comment: I see, so I would navigate to each `<Frame Name="subFrame#" />` using this code, but the `subFrame`s would all be in the same `xaml` file?

Comment: This lets you use one "master" page which is always visible, but each page for the sub-frame would be in a separate .xaml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean specifically the behavior of being able to go back (thus meaning you have a navigation stack) you have access to it with:

```
((Frame)Window.Current.Content).BackStack
```

and you could play with it manually also.

You could pass parameters to your navigate methods and in your on navigated to have access to the passed parameters (maybe use them to load different page parts)

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var param = e.Parameter as SomeType;
}
```

Comment: Yes I do want to go back, but I think I misworded my post. Basically: within one `.xaml` file (and `.xaml.cs`), I want to be able to move around to different views (pages?) using navigation controls. I guess like the UI stays, but the content changes?

Comment: You mean to only change content dynamically (content being some actual data not related to the outline of the page), but still be able to use the back/forth functionality ?

Comment: Kind of. In one file, I'd like it so I can show data (i.e a login screen, and when you login, it takes you to a launch page, then from there you can view settings etc) but all in the same xaml file

Comment: You could adjust the Visibility property of your controls that are inside the page (e.g. Collapsed/Visible) and use the BackStack to retain go back functionality (maybe there's easier way but can't think of one at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do a lot of work, but this is possible, yes.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="FirstContent"
          Grid.Row="0">
        < ... whatever ... >
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="SecondContent"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Visibility="Collapsed">
        < ... whatever ... >
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="NavigationRow"
          Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        < ... navigation controls down here ... >
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Use the control elements you define in the `NavigationRow` to switch between `FirstContent` and `SecondContent` (or whatever you want) by playing with their `Visibility` properties (plus animations).

Now as to *why* you'd want to do this, I don't know. It's a lot of extra work that you are doing here.